# Iphone lost with not connection

Tags: iphone

Lost my Iphone 6, I didn't activate the lost mode, can't see the phone on my Icloud, is there anyway I can locate my phone or is it lost?

Comment: Why wouldn't you activate the lost function **now**?

Comment: I'm betting that's actually "I didn't set up Find my iPhone" - if so, it's a bit late now :/

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your cellphone provider and ask them to locate it, this will work if the battery hasn't been run down. If it's stolen the thief probably crushed the SIM card and it cannot be located in any manner that I know of..